# Do I need to upgrade from Mavericks GM

Tags: macos, build-version

Although the GM should be identical to the final version, I am concerned about not being able to log into my computer in the future because of an expired developer/trial period.

The App Store normally shows a disabled button for installed apps which also will get future upgrades. However Mavericks shows with the "Download" button.

Should I go through a Mavericks reinstall?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should install the final release of Mavericks.

The seed of Mac OS X 10.9 GM, Mavericks, is different to the edition available through the Mac App Store.

- The seed had build `13A598`.
- The final release is build `13A603`.

This suggests bugs were found and fixed since the final preview release. We have had reports of behaviour changes between the two versions.

[image: About panel for Mac OS X 10.9.0]

Comment: Okay, but how does one install 10.9 on top of 10.9.
I'm stuck on 13A598.

Comment: According to @Francisco-Garcia's experience in the original question, you should be able to download from the Mac App Store. Otherwise restore to a back up and upgrade, or blank your Mac and upgrade.